# Create Calendar object using SpEL

Tags: java, calendar, spring-el

Given a `java.util.Date()`, how do you create a Calendar object using the Spring Expression Language?

This one works:

`<property name="calendarObject" value="#{new java.util.GregorianCalendar()}"/>`

but I need to feed the day, month, and year to its constructor from the `java.util.Date()` date that I have. I would like to use the `java.util.Date().getDay()` method but apparently it's already deprecated.

I tried using the Calendar.setTime() method but it doesn't work since its return type is void.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Calendar` is not expression-friendly.

You can use apache commons lang3 `DateUtils`

```
"#{T(org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils).toCalendar(myDate)}"
```

(where `myDate` is a `Date` bean) or write your own helper class.

Answer (score 7):

You can also call the getTime() method which is inherited like this

```
value="#{new java.util.GregorianCalendar().getTime()}
```

and its possible to set a date like this

```
new java.util.GregorianCalendar(1980,01,01).getTime()
```